# Kernel Panic Error Message

Tags: crash

Got a crash message while restarting. Get same message after reboot:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU 1 PID 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu
Hardware name: gigabyte technology co, ltd, to be filled by OEM /F2A88XM-HD3
```

Answer (score 1):

Exact same issue.  Go into "safe mode" ("Advanced" mode on Ubuntu boot screen) and choose the earlier version (3.13.0-**33**-generic).

Once you're back on your desktop you can remove the problematic kernel by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic
```

Comment: Mahalo. very useful.